# Bootstrap Modal will not appear

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have added a bootstrap modal to my page but on button click it is not appearing even though I have it working in another project and it is setup the exact same way.

I'm lost with how to going about solving this, when I click on the button nothing happens.

Here is my code:

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input class="button" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#employeedropdownscan" value="Click Here" ">

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade " id="employeedropdownscan " tabindex="-1 " role="dialog " aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle " aria-hidden="true ">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered " role="document ">
    <div class="modal-content ">
        <div class="modal-header ">
        <h5 class="modal-title " id="exampleModalLongTitle ">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button " class="close " data-dismiss="modal " aria-label="Close ">
            <span aria-hidden="true ">&times;</span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body ">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer ">
        <button type="button " class="btn btn-secondary " data-dismiss="modal ">Close</button>
        <button type="button " class="btn btn-primary ">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: @AndrewSavetchuk no, nothing appears in the console I have no idea what the issue may be

Comment: Can you try using <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#employeedropdownscan">Click Here</button> just in case

Comment: @AndrewSavetchuk I have tried that, I just tried again but still nothing. I have also tried to use an onclick function to try and show the modal using ```$('#employeedropdownscan').modal('show') ``` but still no luck

Comment: Can you upload your code to CodePen so I can take a look?

Comment: Or here as a code snippet so we can launch it

Comment: @AndrewSavetchuk sure I'll do that right now

Comment: You use CSS from Bootstrap 4.0.0 and JS from Bootstrap 3.7.7. It should not work

Comment: @GlebKemarsky ah yes you are right, I don't know how I missed that. Reason it was working in the other project was because there was a navbar being included on the page that was using the proper JS Bootstrap...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You use CSS from Bootstrap 4.0.0 and JS from Bootstrap 3.7.7. It should not work. Let us use 3.4.1 :)
2. The `id` attribute of your modal has one extra space on the end. Let's delete it.
3. And we have the same extra space at the end of `data-dismiss` attributes. It blocks the close buttons. Let's fix it too.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<input class="button" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#employeedropdownscan" value="Click Here" ">

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade " id="employeedropdownscan" tabindex="-1 " role="dialog " aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle " aria-hidden="true ">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content ">
        <div class="modal-header ">
        <h5 class="modal-title " id="exampleModalLongTitle ">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button " class="close " data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close ">
            <span aria-hidden="true ">&times;</span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body ">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer ">
        <button type="button " class="btn btn-secondary " data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button " class="btn btn-primary ">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, use these imports to make it work.

**CSS and JavaScript versions of Bootstrap should match.**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

---

**Secondly, do not put spaces at the end of attributes.**

Except for imports, I was able to find two more issues in your code due to excessive spaces in HTML attributes.

1. Bootstrap can not find the target modal element
2. When the modal is opened, the close button is not working

Reason:

1. `id="employeedropdownscan "`
2. `data-dismiss="modal "`

How to fix:

1. `id="employeedropdownscan"`
2. `data-dismiss="modal"`

---

Full code / Working snippet

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input class="button" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#employeedropdownscan" value="Click Here">

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="employeedropdownscan" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true ">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">
            Modal title
          </h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```